# Stuff shown in designer is not the size it would be at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, designer, windows-forms-designer

This is the time of great desperation. Windows form designer is lying:

```
TTTTTTTT                             TTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTT                             TTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTT                             TTTTTTTT
TTTTTTTT    <- Designer Runtime-> 

LLLLLLLL                             LLLLLLLL
LLLLLLLL                             LLLLLLLL
```

(T = Text Box, L = Label)

Text box (multi-line) and List box shown perfectly edge to edge with my label in designer became much shorter and leave a blank in between when I actually run it. **The form does not contain any actual code beyond designer generated lines.** <s>Docking</s> Anchoring works perfectly (in designer and runtime), its just the size of textbox is wrong.

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 in english. the app itself is localized, and since I changed my system to japanese, there appears to be no easy way for me to run it in a different language to find out how it's like in other languages.

Update: I have tried cleaning the solution, didn't work.

Update: Here's two pictures to explain the situation:
[image: Designer and runtime]
[image: Runtime Resizing, gap size unchanged it seems]

Update: I've checked the designer and runtime size of my control.

Designer:245

Runtime before aligning to the label:158

Runtime after txt.height=label.top-txt.top-3(3 is padding):195

Comment: What have you set the `Anchor` property to on each control?

Comment: What font(s) are you using? is LL a Label or a ListBox? (you mention both) Did you take a look at the code in the Designer.cs file, searching especially for the textbox?

Comment: @petelids Sorry, my bad. Anchoring works perfectly. And docking. but that's not the issue here. I guess now anchoring with a lot of container sounds a good idea but it's a bit late when everything is built. modified post. the anchoring property of the upper one is top,bottom,left, right(there's stuff all around it), lower one is bottom,left,right.

Comment: @TaW (T = Text Box, L = Label). this happens as well when the listbox is in text box's place.

Comment: Your 3rd picture has an interesting title but it looks like the 2nd one. Is that really 'after resizing'? And __how__ did you resize? Again: Did you take a good look at the code in the `designer.cs`??? The answer is __there__ if there is no other code. VS does not lie. (usually)

Comment: If you use localization, then Visual Studio generate control's values(size, location...) for every language. So check size in designer(with Japanese selected) - `myform.Resource.en.resx`

Comment: @TaW Hi, no if you resize to scale you found find out I vertically stretched the window. Sorry for missing some of your first comment, I had a look in designer.cs and resx file(which is the one actually containing the size in numbers), there is only one size all across the languages. And yes it still happen.

Comment: _and resx file(which is the one actually containing the size in numbers),_ ??? resx should contain the resources, like embedded images etc. Everthing you do in the designer goes into the desiger.cs partial class file.. that's the numbers as well as all other property settings!

Comment: @TaW what is the visual studio version you use? did you use localizable forms? in the case of localizing there's only one designer.cs but many .resx files for each language, and each language can have their own control size(well text may vary so that makes sense).

Comment: Oh, right, the Form.langx.resx files. I forgot those, yes they have sizes etc, too. (I don't do a lot of localized programs).. Not sure, what else to guess or try, now. Can you re-create the problem in a small new project?

Comment: Here is another test you can do: write some resizing code and put it into first the form load, then maybe move it to other places to see the effect. You could write something like this `textBox.Height = label.Top - textBox.Top - 5;` and watch if and when it takes effect.. Also: Does the error occurs both with the jp and the standard language version?

Comment: @TaW the second comment is what i did exactly for now - and it works, just not plausible. I tried to make a new project, interestingly only listbox does this now. it does nothing in the default font size also. I used a larger font size (12pt) because that's the accessible font size to everyone (more or less). But this is a new front, i'll see what i can get out of this, thanks!

Comment: and yes, it happens in all languages, at least the ones i've tested